# display custom tables field value in content-type form in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

In drupal i have created custom table where am storing some information.

Now I want to show some data from that table to my particular content type form.

so how to do that in drupal?

for more detail please check here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/114917/how-do-i-display-custom-tables-field-value-in-content-type-form

Comment: Please make the question more readable by providing more details. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using [`HOOK_FORM_ALTER`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) you can set required value as a field default value.

Cheers!!!